# Why I am getting this Error : "columname is not a defined system type" in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted to check the records from back 10 days to current date when I was trying to run this query:

```
select top 1 * 
from tbl_refrence_master 
where ref_id='4110118488' 
  and CONVERT(date, ref_entry_date) between DATEADD(day, -10, convert(ref_entry_date, GETDATE())) 
                                    and CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Type ref_entry_date is not a defined system type.

I can do the same through my source code but I wanted to do by this SQL query.
Why I am getting this error?

Comment: `ref_entry_date` ... does this column exist?

Comment: EDIT: Never mind. The problem is this part: `convert(ref_entry_date, GETDATE())`. I am guessing you meant to convert getdate() to a date.

Comment: ref_entry_date this column exist..and yes i was trying to same  convert getdate() to a date..

Comment: suggest me any suitable solution :)

Comment: What do you expect `convert(ref_entry_date, GETDATE())` to do?

Comment: ref_entry_date used to get current date but now i got i can use server date also..but its giving error 
: 
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM tbl_refrence_master 
WHERE ref_id='4110118488'
    AND ISDATE(ref_entry_date) = 1 
    AND DATEDIFF(d,ref_entry_date,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `ref_entry_date`?  You should be using:

```
select top 1 rm.*
from tbl_refrence_master rm
where ref_id = '4110118488' and
      CONVERT(date, ref_entry_date) between DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE()) and CONVERT(date, getdate());
```

Or, because I don't like to use `between` with dates or datetimes:

```
select top 1 rm.*
from tbl_refrence_master rm
where ref_id = '4110118488' and
      ref_entry_date >= DATEADD(day, -10, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) ) and
      ref_entry_date >= CONVERT(date, getdate());
```

Comment: Thanks sir but its giving error :
> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Comment: after running both above queries same error occur :
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Comment: @SurajBinorkar Please accept the answer if it is worked for you. This helps others to find the worked solution

Comment: sure.. :) and was that my low quality question got -1 ... now i am not able to ask any questions in this forum felling so sad about it.